# regex: strings with a point in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

im having a hardtime with this regex, i need to validate two words with a required point between them, no special characters, no @, no spaces, just the words and the point in the middle. for example:

```
test.test
```

i have been trying with this one, however it doesnt work:

```
^[a-z']*.[a-z']+$
```

can someone please help me with this? i have been stucked for a while now,
thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't define `test.test` as a "two letters string". Do you want a string with letter.letter (`a.a`) or word.word (`something.something`).

Comment: @Balastrong yes thats exactly what i need, sorry...!

Comment: `/^[a-z']+\.[a-z']+$/`

Comment: thats exactly what i needed, thanks!!! 
how can i vote the right answer? @anubhava

Comment: Depending on where you are running your regex you need to escape the right characters. You certainly need to escape the dot. If you are running on a linux shell (e.g.: `echo "aaa" | grep "a\+"`), with many basic commands you have to escape the + character as well. Some later or advanced commands (like egrep) don't need that.
Be sure you figure out what needs to be escaped in your environment.

Comment: You may accept answer by @dang as he was the first one to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot is the wildcard operator, it must be escaped with a backslash, `\`.

[This Wiki on Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) contains info about the wildcard and other common characters for RegEx under "Basic Concepts"

Answer (score 2):

Escape the dot with slash  to make it literal dot otherwise it will match any character

`^[a-z']+\.[a-z']+$`

In regular expressions, the dot (.) is a special character used to match any one character.

Use the *backslash* to escape any special character and interpret it literally; for example:

```
\\ (escapes the backslash)
\[ (escapes the bracket)
\{ (escapes the curly brace)
\. (escapes the dot)
```